# Make one div overlay another from the left side

Tags: html, css

Here is my question, i have 2 divs and want bottom one to overlay upper div without cuttng it's space but being transparent to it. This code is only to show my problem. Margin-top like this is not how i want to fix this.

```css
.main{
  padding-left:30%;
}

p{
  color:red;
}

.divImg{
  margin-top:-20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
  <div class="divImg"><img src=https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/maria_mitchells_195th_birthday-2005006.2-hp.jpg></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if this is acceptable but if i got warning i will delete it since i couldn't apply your resolutions to my problem.

here is website - http://www.plaforma.me/workshop-2/ 
I need to put those 2 ships near the end  to upper lightblue blackground div from both left and right, to make whole div transparent to those 2 images left and right.

EDIT 2 - SOLUTION - Got it, it was z-index problem.

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: Do you have a reference image or description of the specific transparency you're looking for?

Comment: I'm using this just as an example to not post big chunk code of mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for CSS `z-index`.

Container has to be relative.

```css
.main{
  padding-left:30%;
  position:relative;
}

p{
  color:red;
  z-index:2;
}

.divImg{
  margin-top:-20%;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
  <div class="divImg"><img src=https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/maria_mitchells_195th_birthday-2005006.2-hp.jpg></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me try that actually on my website if would work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to have the image to the left of the text but not overlap?
If so, take the second div that contains the image and put it before your div that contains the text in your HTML file. I used a simple float on the image and then relative position to move your text down and align it. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
p{
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  color:red;

}

.divImg{
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but what i am trying is to one div overlay another div without taking each other space but being transparent one to another.  User NiMusco did it properly but i can't apply it to my actual website

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

If so, your problem was that the `main` text's position was not absolute, therefore the image's `div` affected its position.

```css
.main{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

p{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divImg"><img src=https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2013/maria_mitchells_195th_birthday-2005006.2-hp.jpg></div>
  <div class="main"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```